# WPF & WCF relationships

Tags: wpf, wcf

I heard that WPF is more suitable than WinForms for working with WCF.

Is it true, and if so, why?

Comment: I don't think so. You heard this from where? What arguments were provided in order to support this statement?

Comment: I don't see any reason why WPF would work better with WCF than Winforms... WCF is totally independant of what system is calling it - Winforms, WPF, console app, ASP.NET - they're all the same to WCF. WHoever told you this ought to back up his claim with some facts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing that would make the combination any easier than they are separately, or easier than the combination of WinForms and WCF. The two technologies are completely independent.

It seems that perhaps this idea comes from the fact they were released together as part of .Net 3.0, but this has no bearing on this matter.